# How can I use styled-components CDN build on browser?

Tags: html, styled-components

**index.html**

I'm getting the CDN file from:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/4.3.2/styled-components-macro.cjs.min.js"></script>`

How can I access the `styled` function?

`const {styled} = window.styled-components` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`styled-components-macro.cjs.min.js` is not [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd), so if you include this file you did not get global variable.

> If you're not using a module bundler or package manager we also have a global ("UMD") build hosted on the unpkg CDN. Simply add the following `<script>` tag to the bottom of your HTML file:

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
```

> Once you've added `styled-components` you will have access to the global `window.styled` variable.

```js
const Component = window.styled.div`
  color: red;
`
```

source: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#installation

---

**UPDATE FROM OP:**

Newer versions has stopped working (probably v5) from the URL above. But it's still working like this on v4:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components@4.0.1/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: I still get TypeError: window.styled is undefined. Please Help.

Comment: @Frumentius It has stopped working... But I can confirm that it was working before. Probably some newer version broke it.

Comment: @Frumentius v4 still works. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Currently the latest version of v4 is 4.4.1. You can use like this `<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components@4/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 10):

For version 5, as mentioned in the [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#installation) you now need to include `react-is` before `styled-components`

```html
<!-- react, react-dom dev bundles -->
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<!-- react-is -->
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-is/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>

<!-- styled-components -->
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<script>
  const Component = window.styled.div`background-color: green;`;
</script>
```

Comment: This should be a new accepted answer as it is more relevant to what people are searching today