# Nesting styles ignores the styled component's styling

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

I'm using styled-components via cdn. If I do not nest styles, my components are styled. If I try to nest, none of the styles take effect.

```
const AComponent = () => {
  return (
    <StyledComponent>
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </StyledComponent>
  )
}

// using this shows a red background color
const StyledComponent = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
`

// using this doesn't style anything - not even a red background color
const StyledComponent = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
  p {
    color: black;
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a bit of twist and found the below code working.

```
export const StyledComponent = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
  & > p {
    color: green;
  }
`;
```

Here is the supporting link for explanation https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/330

Comment: This doesn't work for me - there are no styles on the component.

Comment: Please find the working code sandbox link 'https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-dust-cxy9j9?file=/src/App.js' for the same.

Comment: That example isn't using styled components via a cdn which I think might be causing the issue.

Comment: In case you are using CDN url, then I believe 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985205/how-can-i-use-styled-components-cdn-build-on-browser' can be of use.